# Adding floating action button to the layout with navigation drawer and toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, navigation-drawer, floating-action-button

I could able to create an app with `toolbar` and sliding `navigation drawer` with `recycleView`.

Now I am trying to add `Floating action button` but I am unable to figure out right place to add the button.

I am trying to add fab bottom right.

Below is my activity_main.xml file

```
     <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And `Fragment` layout file fragment_navigtion_drawer.xml is

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/drawerColor">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerDrawerImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/drawertitlebackground">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/drawerAppImage"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

             />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Make search easy"
            android:id="@+id/drawerSubTitle"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/containerDrawerImage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is the the code for FAB

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/container_body"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:rippleColor="#F06292"/>
```

I am trying to put this in `Linearlayout` under `FrameLayout` in `activity_main.xml` file. I could see the button appears bottom right.
But when I run the application, there shows a rectangle strip with same height which hides the content behind it. The rectangle strip is covering from left to right including the fab button but fab button is coming on its top.

Content behind is the `fragment` with `Listview`. So entries at bottom are getting hided because the fab button area is covered as rectangle.

I need just button appear and rest of area should be covered with `fragment` data i.e. `listview` in my case.

Its clue less for me where the issue is.

**Solved:**
I am able to resolve the issue by rewriting `activity_main.xml` in below way. Now FAB button appears properly. Below is updated one.

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/container_body"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/container_body"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                app:fabSize="normal"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"

                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:rippleColor="#F06292"/>

        </FrameLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I needed exactly the three things together -  Drawer Layout, Toolbar and Floating Action Menu and was facing issues with proper layout. your solution solved mine as well... Thx .

Comment: Awesome solution. Great one . Thanks